# ¿Cómo puedo recorrer este JSON para mi menú basado en roles?

Tags: php, json, codeigniter-3

¿Como recorrer mi JSON para luego utilizarlo en el menú, una vez que lo haya recorrido bien mi array. En la parte de *home* llamo a la vista como `<?php  $this->load->view('menu/menu'); ?>`, solo que al visualizarlo en `http://localhost/storeLTE/home`, me dice que no está declara la variable. ¿Como hacer para pasar todo, recorrerlo, y al momento de pasarlo al *home*, igual se vea bien?

Login controller

```
public function getModules(){
        if($this->session->userdata('log')){
            $data = $this->session->userdata('log');
            $menu = array();
            $seccions = $this->module->get_rows();
            foreach ($seccions as $index => $seccion){
               $modules = $this->module->query("SELECT CONCAT('".$seccion['id']."',storelte_modulo.id) AS id,CONCAT('".base_url('assets/img/sidebar')."','/',storelte_modulo.icon) as icon, storelte_modulo.modulo AS value,storelte_modulo.seccion_id,CONCAT('".base_url()."',storelte_modulo.url) AS  url FROM storelte_modulo INNER JOIN storelte_modulo_perfil ON  storelte_modulo_perfil.modulo_id = storelte_modulo.id WHERE seccion_id = $seccion[id] AND storelte_modulo_perfil.perfiles_id = $data[id] AND storelte_modulo_perfil.STATUS = 1");
                $seccions[$index]['data']= $modules;
                if (!count($seccions[$index]['data']))
                    unset($seccions[$index]);
            }
            foreach ($seccions as $item)
                array_push($menu,$item);
          $this->json($menu);
          $this->load->view('menu/menu',$menu);
        }
    }
```

Menu view

```
<aside class="main-sidebar">
  <section class="sidebar">
    <ul class="sidebar-menu">
     <li class="treeview">
        <?php foreach ($variable as $key => $value): ?>

        <?php endforeach ?>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</aside>
```

Home view

```
<!-- Left side column. contains the logo and sidebar -->
       <?php  $this->load->view('menu/menu'); ?>
```

JSON

```
[
  {
    "id":"1",
    "seccion":"Inventario",
    "data":[
      {
        "id":"11",
        "icon":"http:\/\/localhost\/storeLTE\/assets\/img\/sidebar\/items.png",
        "value":"Productos",
        "seccion_id":"1",
        "url":"http:\/\/localhost\/storeLTE\/inventory\/product"
      }]
  },
  {
    "id":"2",
    "seccion":"Compras",
    "data":[
      {
        "id":"22",
        "icon":"http:\/\/localhost\/storeLTE\/assets\/img\/sidebar\/suppliers.png",
        "value":"Compras",
        "seccion_id":"2",
        "url":"http:\/\/localhost\/storeLTE\/purchase\/purchase"
      }]
  },
  {
    "id":"3",
    "seccion":"Ventas",
    "data":[
      {
        "id":"33",
        "icon":"http:\/\/localhost\/storeLTE\/assets\/img\/sidebar\/sales.png",
        "value":"Ventas",
        "seccion_id":"3",
        "url":"http:\/\/localhost\/storeLTE\/sale\/sales"
      }]
  },
  {
    "id":"4",
    "seccion":"Reportes",
    "data":[
      {
        "id":"44",
        "icon":"http:\/\/localhost\/storeLTE\/assets\/img\/sidebar\/employees.png",
        "value":"Provedores",
        "seccion_id":"4",
        "url":"http:\/\/localhost\/storeLTE\/provider\/provider"
      }]
  }]
```

Comment: ¿Es un objeto JSON o una cadena codificada como tal?

Desde mi punto de vista, lo propio es que conviertas el json en un array y trabajes con ella:

    $menuArray = json_decode($menuJSON, true);

Comment: el problema que es cuando quiero regresar la vista a mi otra vista home me dice q mis variables esta indefinidas como pudiera resolver eso

Answer (score 1):

Yo transformaría el json en un array PHP y así lo trabajas como quieras cómodamente:

```
$url = "ruta-de-tu-json.json";
$string = file_get_contents($url);
$array = json_decode($string, true);
```

Y trabajas con `$array`